Trying to build a lib working with VitePress, Vite build error: failed to resolve import "@siteData"
I'm trying to build a plugin(?) for VitePress, using Vite as the building tool. When I import and use it locally, it works fine. However, when I build the lib, errors occurred:
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@siteData" from ".../node_modules/.pnpm/vitepress@1.4.2_@.../node_modules/vitepress/dist/client/app/data.js".

Reproduction

VitePress useData API relies on importing @siteData, which is a virtual file provided by VitePress Vite plugin. Therefore, it should be left as-is, VitePress core can handle it.
Also, being a peer dependency, vitepress should be omitted from the bundle.
vite.config.ts:
 import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
 import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

 export default defineConfig({
   build: {
     lib: {
       entry: 'src/index.ts',
       formats: ['es'],
     },
     rollupOptions: {
-      external: ['vue'],
+      external: ['@siteData', 'vitepress', 'vue'],
     },
     target: 'esnext',
   },
   plugins: [vue()],
 });

